# How to include jQuery from Global Libraries into my page in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I cannot understand what is the advantages of having jQuery in *"Global Libraries"* list?

Can I somehow include any javascript Global Library into my html page or should I just copy/paste content of this library to new file in my project and include it manually to html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global libraries are needed for code completion in the web applications when there are no explicit includes in all the pages or when you are editing JS files that have access to other libraries, but there is no way to specify it directly in the script.

Of course you need to have a copy of the library in your project or reference its URL in HTML pages.

Comment: So, I suggest JetBrains to think about such feature. It would be very convenient if I can just choose library and HTML page and IDEA automatically copy this library into my project and add link to library at HTML page I selected.